# XCode+SVN coloring the modified lines?

Tags: svn, xcode, diff, text-coloring

I am probably asking for too much: does anyone know a way to get XCode color the lines of code according to their subversion status (modified, added, etc.)?
It would be nice to have it integrated in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Xcode does not provide this functionality. The only way I can think of is to write a script that will do the job.

Comment: That's what I thought... *sigh* Any ideas on how to colorize the code via a script?